# Best signature fonts

Tags: photoshop

Are there any good realistic looking signature fonts you guys know of?

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search for "[signature fonts](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=signature%20fonts&aq=&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=6782d3fc39a1f682&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=6782d3fc39a1f682&ion=1&biw=1261&bih=885)" turns up quite a few results.

Some that looked good:

- [Alako](http://www.urbanfonts.com/fonts/Alako.htm)
- [Denistina](http://www.dafont.com/denistina.font?nb_ppp=50&psize=l&text=Graphic%20Mania)

[There's a bunch of good ones here](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=603).

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite handwriting fonts is [League Script #1](http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/fonts/15-league-script-1) - which is also conveniently open source.

It's a very flowing font, so it might not be suitable for masculine styles.